# How to show only one row with max date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on my database project right now. I made a view which shows info about guests. As you can see, there are two rows with Frank Collins. How can I show only one row with him (with recent date of his stay) using SELECT for the view? [image: picture]

Comment: Use rank query order by dateFrom, and fetch whose rank is 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        SeqNo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LastName,FirstName ORDER BY DateTo DESC),
        *
        FROM Guests
)
SELECT
*
FROM CTE
    WHERE SeqNo = 1
```

This query will return the latest records for each user, if there are multiple records for a first name + last name combination, it will give you the latest one based on dateTo otherwise it will return the record as it is

So you will get only 1 row per guest each time you execute this

Answer (score 2):

I think this the simpliest solution...:

```
select top 1 * from MY_VIEW
where lastname = 'Collins' and firstname = 'Frank'
order by dateto desc
```

or more edible:

```
select top 1 * from MY_VIEW
where lastname + ' ' + firstname = 'Collins Frank'
order by dateto desc
```

Comment: Seems like OP wants one row per guest.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT
A.LASTNAME, A.FIRSTNAME, A.DATEFROM, A.DATETO, A.ROOMNUMBER, A.CITY, A.COUNTRY, A.STATUS, A.DAYS
FROM
(SELECT LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, MAX(DATETO) AS MOST_RECENT_STAY
FROM YOUR_TABLE 
GROUP BY LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME) Z
INNER JOIN
YOUR_TABLE A
ON Z.LASTNAME = A.LASTNAME AND Z.FIRSTNAME = A.FIRSTNAME AND Z.MOST_RECENT_STAY = A.DATETO;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need CTE, just use `TOP WITH TIES` + `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM guests
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY lastname, firstname ORDER BY dateto DESC)
```